# Xcode warnings in frameworks do not show in project navigator unless selected as target

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just discovered that I had a number of warnings in a dynamic framework (swift) that were never appearing in my issue navigator because my main project was selected for building.  Is this normal?  Is there a way to tell Xcode to always display warnings for child frameworks as well?  I don't want to ever accidentally miss warnings like this again simply because I'm building everything.

To be clear, this has nothing to do with the issue filter not being blank.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit the scheme for your app. Go to "Build"->Build, press the +, and add your dynamic framework(s).

When I did this, the warnings for my framework appeared immediately, and stay up-to-date just like in the code of the main app.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode only compiles the classes of the target of your scheme.

Therefore it only shows warnings for the current target and compiling errors if it is depending on the dynamic library target.

If you want to see the warnings of other targets just like your dynamic library, try to create a new target + scheme containing all files. You don't need to use it as your main target, but once in a while you can use it to check if you have any unresolved warnings.

Alternative (pure speculations):
I thought to remember that you can depend on multiple targets. Maybe you can apply this technique for your case.

Comment: When you say, "Xcode only compiles all classes of the target corresponding to your target", what exactly does that mean?  I make changes to methods in my framework all the time and just run against the main project, and clearly it's recompiling the framework (presumably when it detects that it has changed).  If it wasn't doing this then my changes wouldn't work.

Comment: I am sorry, I rephrased it.

Comment: Are you saying that I would create a target (in my main project perhaps?) that has all of the files from my frameworks too?  I don't know if I'm understanding you correctly.  I actually have two dynamic frameworks and one main project.  All of the code is used from each (i.e. it's not like I have a target that uses some classes and not others).  I wouldn't want to copy (or strangely include) all of the framework files into the main project just so I could compile them at the same time, if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, i know it is a hack, but this new target is only for testing for warnings in your libraries. Therefore you could include child frameworks/dynamic libraries (source code) and it would check the sourcode for warnings. You should not use this for your project development, only for checking for warnings like you asked to!